# What's the reason Docker Ubuntu official image would exit immediately when you run/start it?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, docker

I understand that a container will exit when the main process exit. My question is about the reason behind it, not how to get it to work. I of course know that I could pass the parameter `-it` to start with interactive mode.

The Ubuntu image will run `/bin/bash` when it starts according to the image Dockerfile. Shouldn't bash process wait for user input commands and not exit? (just like when you run `/bin/bash` in the host machine, it would start an interactive shell and wait for user inputs and not exit) Why would the Docker Ubuntu's bash exit right away?

Comment: Without `-it` it has no TTY, and no `stdin` attached, so bash starts and completes directly after. You can keep it running by adding the `-d` option (so `docker run -dit ubuntu`) to start it in detached mode

Comment: @thaJeztah That sounds like something that should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Ah, perhaps it is, yes, sorry, bad habbit :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `-it` the container has no TTY, and no `stdin` attached, so bash starts and completes directly after.

You can keep the container running by adding the `-d` option (so `docker run -dit ubuntu`) to start it in detached mode